# Using display:inline for centered menus vs display:block

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Say you have a horizontal, graphical nav menu where each menu item is variable width (controlled by padding rather than a width to the `<li>` element). This means you can't truly know the width of the ul (in order to center it) because the text is different sizes in different browsers.

Up until now I would either

A) Just eye it and use margin-left on the ul

B) use jquery to calculate the width and then set set it as an inline-style so that the width can be set, and then it can be margin: auto'd.

But someone just told me I can use display: inline and it works fine, without using float, and it always centers? has anyone heard of this? he's kind of new and can't quite explain it so i'm curious what you guys think. He says he thinks text-align: center. I dont see how this would work on a menu though.. which is not text?

Comment: There are as many ways to center something with CSS as there are to write the markup for it. Post your code and we can help explain what is going on.

Comment: I see what he did... he set the ul to text-align: center; then he set the li elements to display:inline; i assume this tricks the browser into thinking each list item is text, and then it centers variable width list items properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any text level element can be centred. It'll be centered according to its parent element. Which should be a block level element.

The following menu can be centred,

```
<ul id="ul">
<li>one</li>
<li>two</li>
<li>January</li>
<li>September</li>
</ul>
```

Using this CSS

```
ul#ul{text-align:center;}
ul#ul li{display:inline;}
```

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JG48M/2/) to get an idea

Comment: and this is completely valid/compliant/cross-browser html/css? how the hell have i not heard of this.... damn...

Answer (score 0):

Set the `ul` and `li`s to `display:inline` or `display:inline-block`, and set the `ul`'s container to `text-align:center`. You might have to add `zoom:1` for some older versions of IE to work properly with `inline-block`.

Suggested reading:

- http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html
- http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/24/css-display-inline-block-why-it-rocks-and-why-it-sucks/

Comment: -1 It'll show centred `li` vertically. OP requires it _horizontally_.